# Unable access Webserver in personal router

Tags: web-server, router

I have a Cisco linksys E-1000. It has four wired port and connected to internet. I was connecting one desktop pc using wired, and one laptop using wireless connection. All is managed using DHCP by the router. When I look at the connection information, they bound to the same configuration, the same gateway and the same DNS. All can access to internet.

The desktop IP is 192.168.1.125, connected using wired to router

The laptop IP is 192.168.1.126, connected using wireless to router

The router IP is 192.168.1.1

On the desktop I installing Linux Ubuntu desktop 11.10, and on laptop I installing Ubuntu 12.4, and I created a webserver in the desktop one, run at port 80.

My problem is:
The laptop can ping the desktop, but the desktop cannot ping the laptop, it show destination host unreachable.

Even though the laptop can ping the desktop, it cannot open the webserver at the desktop. It show connection timeout. Please help. I don't know what caused the problem. Is there any difference a connection using cable and wireless? (router see them as different network) Or another thing caused I cannot connect to webserver, like false configuration or something?

My purpose is I want to make a network for developing django apps, and the desktop will be the server.

Sorry if my question is very basic for some people. I'm weak in networking thing, so I need help from you all. many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laptop being unable to reach the desktop's port 80 is likely a firewall issue. I know that Ubuntu uses ufw and is turned on by default. You can try running 'service ufw stop' on the desktop and see if your laptop can read your desktop then.

I'm not sure about why your desktop cannot reach the laptop with a ping though. Running some tests would definitely help though.

Comment: thank you very much. yes you're right it is all about the ufw thing blocked my access to my web server. maybe I should learn more about the ufw, but many thanks for you. :). About the ping, I change the wired port and reset the router, it is working properly now. maybe hardware problem.